# Regular expression for EDU emails with sub domains

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email-validation

I am attempting to create a regular expression for validating edu emails which may or may not have a sub domain. Some schools have emails like "example@hms.harvard.edu" while other schools have emails like "example@stanford.edu".

```
([0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z])+@([0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z])+([0-9]|[a-z]|[A-Z])\.edu$"
```

This is the current regular expression that I have but I am not well versed in these.
I am looking to create an expression that will validate emails with one domain and emails with a subdomain.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, `/^[-\w.]+@[-\w.]+\.edu$/` should be enough.
The only problem with this solution would be, that it can also accept domains like hms..harvard.edu.

To prevent this, you could use this regex instead: `/^[-\w.]+@([-\w]+\.)*[-\w]+\.edu$/`

Edit: use \w instead of [0-9a-zA-Z_]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Would the +\. in the ([-\w]+\.) create an extra period in the case of one domain?

Comment: ([-\w]+\.) matches one or more alphanumeric characters and dashes followed by a period (in your example this would be the 'hms.' part). 
The '*' quantifier defines that this group can occur 0 or more times (so there must not be a subdomain, but there can be multiple subdomains). Therefore 'example@harvard.edu' and 'example@hms.something.harvard.edu' would both also be considered a valid email address.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (modified from http://emailregex.com/ - referenced in [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)):

```
/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+edu))$/
```